# SVN installed on windows to access from linux

Tags: linux, windows, svn, subclipse

I installed subversion server on windows server and started subversion server as windows service. I created some repositorys. The access from windows clients works fine (Tortoise; and with url: svn://Servername/RepositoryA/Entw

But now i want to access from a linux/debian client. I installed subclipse. But i cannot get an access to the svn Repository. I tried with several URL, but there are the answer:

svn: No repository found in ...

Can you help me?

Comment: This is the environment that I have and all is fine. I don't know what `subclipse` is but I use `svn` from the command-line. Example `checkout`: `svn checkout http://servername:port/svn/reponame ./reponame`

Comment: subclipse is a plugin for eclipse. I will try your Suggestion.

Comment: probably firewalls blocking the svn:// port. Try configuring your svn server to use http instead.